# Regex for "To" in java

Tags: java, regex

I get a lot of strings in this format `Person To Company`. For example `Joe To Fedex`. What I need is a simple regex that can get the two different parts of this. I need the person, and the company.

I have come up with this:

```
"\\b\\s[Tt][Oo]\\s\\b"
```

While this isnt quite right, it doesnt really help me actually parse out the pieces that I need. Any ideas on how this canbe accomplished in Java?

Comment: All that will do is detect a case-insentive `to` surrounded by whitespace. You need capture groups (`()`) to 'capture' the joe/fedex text.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s+to\\s+(\\S+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    fromstr = regexMatcher.group(1);
    tostr = regexMatcher.group(2);

}
```

should work for this. (`\S` matches any non-whitespace character. If you want to only match letters, you can use `\p{L}` instead).

Comment: THanks for your response. So I gave this a shot. It worked. But suppose the Person and Company can be multiple words. For Example `Joe Smith To Fedex Delivery Services`. Then this fails to parse them. Any idea on how it could be update to do that?

Comment: If that really is your entire string, then I'd go with @FranciscoPaulo's suggestion. Otherwise, we'd need more info how to find out where the names start and end.

Comment: I guess I could edit it to be everything before the to is the Person, and everything after the To is the company

Comment: @user489041: OK, then you should accept his answer because that will give you exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

Split the String like this:

```
String[] split = someString.split("(?i)\\s+TO\\s+")
```

First section is in split[0] and the second one in split[1]

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to get the group method in Matcher.

```
String regx = "(\\w*)\\s[Tt][Oo]\\s(\\w*)";
String src = "Joe To Fedex";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regx).matcher(src);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Can do `regx="(\\w*)\\sto\\s(\\w*)"; ... matcher = Pattern.compile(regx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(src);`